# jQuery - How to set width during it is increasing?

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I am trying to use following codes to create a continuely animatation

```
var running = function() {
  w = jQuery('#belt').width();
  if(w >= 940)
    jQuery('#belt').width(0);

  jQuery('#belt').animate({width: '+=235px'}, duration, 'linear');
}

jQuery(document).everyTime(duration, running);
```

But it doesn't work, the width didn't get reset but continuely increasing, did i write wrong?

Comment: If really you want to use everyTime, you'll need to make your first parameter a string, that is:`$(document).everyTime("5s", function(i) { }, 0);`

Comment: @diEcho, by this way, my animation get reset now. But a new problem appears which is there is a sudden stop between animations now, any ideas?

Comment: increase duration time and what is the need of using 'linear'??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [the `complete` parameter for `jQuery#animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to define a function that should be executed when the animation is completed. Add some recursion, et voilà:

```
jQuery.fn.continuousAnimation = function() {
  var $this = this;
  return $this.animate({ 'width': '+=235px' }, 400, 'linear', function() {
    $this.width(0).continuousAnimation();
  });
};

jQuery('#belt').continuousAnimation();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mathias/dRpgv/

Answer (score 0):

what is the value of `duration`??

better to use

> setInterval(function() {
>       // refresh list }, 5000)

where the second parameter is the number of milliseconds.

**Note on everyTime**

If really you want to use everyTime, you'll need to make your first parameter a string, that is:

> $(document).everyTime("5s",
>   function(i) { }, 0);

no such need of using 'linear'
if your animate sudden stops then check check the `duration`, increase animation time or use `slow`

> jQuery('#belt').animate({width:
>   '+=235px'}, 'slow');

Comment: duration was set to '1s', and the sudden stop seems because animate() doesn't work with '1s'; I changed duration to '3s' now and hard code animate() to animate(.., 3000, ..), then the width won't get reset again...

Comment: @Edward width will be reset after 3000 ms. btw  don't set same value for animate and everytime , `everytime()` duration will be greater than `animate()` duration

Comment: make everytime duration greater than animate duration works, it seems jQuery need some time to execute the width reset, but this method also add an interval between animations, i tried to use 3000 against 2990, it works in chrome while fails in firefox. with 3000 against 2900, works in firefox too but not smooth and i guess it won't work on computers with low performance

Comment: @edward its not like that. u just clear your cache and try again.